# SPOTFIRE: Clean dat in the default Data Table

Tags: tibco, spotfire

I am looking to clean data in one particular colum on my default data Table.

The column looks like this:

```
    x
-----------
FR / NYC-PAR
FR - NYC-PAR
```

I want to change all the values of `FR - NYC-PAR` as `FR / NYC-PAR` without adding a new calculated column. Would this be possible by writing an expression? I also dont want to replace the data table.
Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you:

`Tools > Insert Transformations > Calculate and replace column`

Then use this expression, where c1 is the name of the column:

`RXReplace([C1],"[/]","-","") as [C1]`